# how to change upload path in froala wysiwyg

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, froala

I'm working on project which used Froala 2.4.0 WYSIWYG editor.
I'm using xampp and localhost test.
I can't use local path for upload images and files, all file and image upload in: https://i.froala.com/
But I want upload all file and image to http://localhost/uploads

How to do?
I tried in froala website but I cannot do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for upload image :

- create "uploads" directory in localhost,
- create "images" directory in uploads,
- create a php file "upload_image.php" in localhost with this content:

  ```
  <?php
  // Allowed extentions.
  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "blob");

  // Get filename.
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

  // Get extension.
  $extension = end($temp);

  // An image check is being done in the editor but it is best to
  // check that again on the server side.
  // Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

  if ((($mime == "image/gif")
  || ($mime == "image/jpeg")
  || ($mime == "image/pjpeg")
  || ($mime == "image/x-png")
  || ($mime == "image/png"))
  && in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)) {
        // Generate new random name.
        $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;

        // Save file in the uploads folder.
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/uploads/images/" . $name);

        // Generate response.
        $response = new StdClass;
        $response->link = "http://localhost/uploads/images/" . $name;
        echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
  }
     ?>
  ```

and add this script plugin to your editor page :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="froala_editor_directory/js/plugins/image.min.js">
```

and edit "image.min.js" change imageUploadURL parameter to:

```
  imageUploadURL:"http://localhost/upload_image.php",
```

and repeat all step for file upload :

- create "files" directory in uploads,
- create a php file "upload_file.php" in localhost with this content:

  ```
  <?php
  // Get filename.
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

  // Get extension.
  $extension = end($temp);

  // An image check is being done in the editor but it is best to
  // check that again on the server side.
  // Do not use $_FILES["file"]["type"] as it can be easily forged.
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

  $allowedExts = array(
      'pdf', 
      'doc', 
      'docx', 
      'xls', 
      'xlsx'
  );

  $allowedMimeTypes = array(
      'application/x-pdf', 
      'application/pdf',
      'application/msword', 
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
      'application/vnd.ms-excel', 
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  );

  if (in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts) AND in_array($mime, $allowedMimeTypes)) {
        // Generate new random name.
        $name = sha1(microtime()) . "." . $extension;

        // Save file in the uploads folder.
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/uploads/files/" . $name);

        // Generate response.
        $response = new StdClass;
        $response->link = "http://localhost/uploads/files/" . $name;
        echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
  }
    ?>
  ```

and add this script plugin to your editor page :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="froala_editor_directory/js/plugins/file.min.js">
```

and edit "file.min.js" change fileUploadURL parameter to:

```
  fileUploadURL :"http://localhost/upload_file.php",
```

Finally, if you get the error "Something went wrong, please try again", you should **enable extension = php_fileinfo.dll**,

Good luck :)

Comment: Nice solution! It works for me, but, if you don´t mind, would you have a similar solution for VIDEO? Thanks.