# Froala editor not work uploader

Tags: froala

I use Froala editor for upload

But in this line error :

> 'The Froala Editor SDK library requires the ' . $ext . ' extension.'

Code :

```
require_once 'editor/lib/FroalaEditor.php';

try {
    $response = FroalaEditor_Image::upload('/upload/');
    echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(404);
}
```

Comment: I found answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361404/how-to-change-upload-path-in-froala-wysiwyg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor-php-sdk#dependencies
You need to enable `fileinfo` extension in PHP.

You can look here: [Install fileinfo php extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189266/install-fileinfo-php-extension)